# Conditions under which Laplace's equation inside rectangle has solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider $u(x,y)$ satisfying Laplace's equation inside a rectangle $(0 < x < L)$ and $(0 < y < H)$, subject to the boundary conditions: $$\begin{cases} u_{x}(0,y)=0 \\ u_{x}(L,y)=0 \\ u_{y}(x,0) = 0 \\ u_{y}(x,H) = f(x)\end{cases} $$

My text book says to determine the physical condition under which there is a solution to the problem (without actually solving the problem). At the back of the book, it says that "the total heat flow across the boundary must equal zero in equilibrium (without sources; i.e., Laplace's equation). Thus $\int_{0}^{L} f(x)dx = 0$ for a solution.

I'm not a physics student, and weak in vector calculus, so I would like to understand what this translates into mathematically. I'd just like to understand when Laplace's equation with these boundary conditions has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Gauss Divergence Theorem, we have
$$ \iint_{(0,L)\times(0,H)} \nabla \cdot \nabla u \, dV = \int_{\partial((0,L)\times(0,H))} \nabla u \cdot n \, d\sigma $$
Since $u(x,y)$ satisfies the Laplace Equation, $\nabla \cdot \nabla u = \triangle u = 0$ on $(0, L)\times(0, H)$ and the integral on the left hand side vanishes.

Putting the boundary conditions into the integral on the right hand side, we obtain the desired result:
$$ 0 = \int_0^L f(x) \, dx$$

Comment: A tad cryptic, no? I see what you're saying but maybe not as useful for someone new to these sorts of calculations.

Comment: I agree that I am not clear enough here. At least I should have added some more steps.

Comment: Great, thanks for the edits. Hope the OP agrees!